# How to automatically submit responses to a google form

Tags: php, google-api, google-forms

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically fill out a google form using php.

I have all of the data I want to enter in a database and have a link to the form.

I'm not actually sure if there is a google forms api but i'v seen references to it online so i'm hoping it exists.

Comment: there is an API for creation, but not filling out (because that's obviously a little suspect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatically filling in google forms was not allowed.

I will find a different way to do it!